# Validating Azure B2C Token in app that didn't authenticate user

Tags: azure, active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have a scenario whereby, a user would sign in/sign up to Azure AD B2C from a frontend application. There after they would make calls to an API application (with a JWT token) separate from this frontend. The requirement is that the API application validates a user's token and decides whether to execute the request. I can send the JWT token from frontend to API using the auth header. I can receive it in the API also. The challenge is to now validate that this token is not faked by a man-in-the-middle or just being abused by someone who got hold of it. I know each token comes with a timestamp and can be checked for expiration. However, this is not sufficient. I need to check it against Azure AD B2C somehow.

Update: the API is a NodeJs based Azure Functions app

Comment: Signature checks are how you check a token has not been modified. Is your token signed somehow now?

Comment: Hi, Yes. It is now all working accordingly. But essentially, all I had to do is check the signature by calling the verify() method of the jsonwebtoken library and pass in the key found in the jwks endpoint

Answer (score 2):

You can validate the signatures of the token in your API app. A Token is signed by asymmetric keys.

Every user flow in AzureB2C has a associated metadata document which has all the details about the keys in the tag "jwks_uri"

[image]

"jwks_uri": "https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_pe",

you can fetch the key details from the link under jwks_uri tag and use it to validate the signature. Also remember these keys are rotated so you need to get the latest once every 24 hours.

Sample :-
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/user_info

Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview

Answer (score 1):

See this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi). The [API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) is protected using the `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` to verify the signature of the token. All Azure AD B2C tokens are signed JWTs. The sample code will find the metadata endpoint of your policy+tenant combination, and use the public key to ensure that the token signature is valid/unmodified and has been signed by the private keyholder (AAD B2C)

Comment: I think this is also in the right direction, however too specific. This assumes the environment is a .NET environment. I have updated the question to specify the technologies

Comment: Same principals apply. See this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/tree/master/)